# Can I create values with PHP and expected them to be readable by JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm making a site for myself, and I'm trying to implement some javascript for instant calculations, but I'm having some issues:

1. Is there any way I can avoid typing

   ```
   level_prices["3"]=3;
   level_prices["4"]=4;
   ```

   ... etc. up to 90: in other words, is there any way I can do like I did in the PHP code and make it `create` this value until 90, which looks a lot cleaner?
2. Why is this returning `$Undefined`? I suspect that it's not getting the value from the HTML form, but the code looks correct ...

Here is my code:

relevant HTML/PHP:

```
 <form action="" id="priceCalcForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <table class="table">
   <tbody>

     <tr> <!-- first row, with css -->

        <td style="width:50%;">
            <select name="fromlevel" id="fromlevel" onchange="calculateTotal()" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">
                <option value="none" name="none">0</option>

                <?php 
                $i = 1;

                while ($i < 91) {
                    echo '
                    <option value=' . $i . ' name=' . $i . '>' . $i . '</option>';
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>  
            </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </form>
```

Included JS:

```
var level_prices= new Array();
level_prices["None"]=0;
level_prices["1"]=1;
level_prices["2"]=2;

function getLevelPrice()
{
    var levelSetPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["priceCalcForm"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
    var selectedLevel = theForm.elements["fromlevel"];

    //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
    //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
    levelSetPrice = level_prices[selectedLevel.value];

    //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
    return levelSetPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
//Here we get the total price by calling our function
//Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return     together
    var LevelPrice = getLevelPrice();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Leveling $"+LevelPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

I consider myself decent with PHP, but its first time I am using JS.

Comment: I forgot to add the <div id="totalPrice></div> but its there.

Comment: Is the error coused by the JS getting executed prior to the PHP ? And the PHP not echoing the rest of the select values ?

Answer (score 0):

1) use a loop:

```
var level_prices = {}; // object literal not array!
level_prices['none'] = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= 90; i++ ) {
   level_prices[i] = i;
}
```

the first to lines could also be written like this (already define the none-property):

```
var level_prices = {'none': 0};
```

2) level_prices is not an array it is an object-literal (see part 1 of my answer)

see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BkGxq/

(also notice that i deleteted the inline onchange handler from your markup and put it to the javascript (at the bottom)

Comment: Ty very much, implementing it now :)

Comment: Ty! worked, if i could give you points i would do it :)

Or well, the other part of the problem was that i had another form, called the same, which i will later use for some calculations, but i changed the name of that, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any variable in PHP (except Resource-type variables) can be dumped directly into JavaScript with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).